# Manifolds , Submanifolds and Embeddings

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, submanifold

I am studying for a differential geometry exam and our professor gave us the following practice question but the whole class is having trouble with it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Suppose that C $\subset$ $\mathbb{R}^3$ is a smooth embedded curve. Let M be the set of all pair (p,v) where p is a point of C and v $\in$ $\mathbb{R}^3$ is a vector perpendicular to the tangent line C at p.

(a) Describe a smooth structure on M in which M is a manifold. Hint: you might need more than one chart. Hint: Don't write out the transition maps.

(b) Explain why M is an embedded submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^3$ x $\mathbb{R}^3$.

(c) Suppose that C is connected. Prove that the map (p,v) $\in$ M $\rightarrow$ p+v $\in$ $\mathbb{R}^3$ is an embedding just when C is a subset of a line in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: Are you lost on the entire question, or are you okay with parts of it? If the latter, can you perhaps say a bit about where you're stuck?

Comment: Hi Andrew. I'm stuck on the entire question.

Comment: I think I've figured out (a). I just need help with (b) and (c) now I think.

Comment: For (b), you might show that locally along $C$, there exists an orthonormal pair of smooth vector fields perpendicular to the tangent lines. (The normal and binormal fields of the Frenet frame work if $C$ is sufficiently generic, though suitable fields aren't difficult to construct in general.) For (c), it's enough to show that if $C$ is not a line segment, then there exist points $p$ and $q$ whose normal planes intersect.

Comment: Full marks blahblahblah ;)